# Smoothing of a surface

Tags: smoothing

A land surveyor made a topographic map of a property in the hills by measuring the elevation at different points. The x-y coordinates are more or less "random", meaning no regular grid:
[image: Text]

Because the elevation measurements (z-coordinate) seem to be pretty noisy I would like to smoothen them (that is smoothen the surface, so the x-y coordinates of the data points should remain unchanged).

For clarification here is an excerpt of the data (x-y are in UTM, z is the elevation in meter. There are 1066 data points in total):

```
439304.3190,2132685.7270,117.0620  
439289.3550,2132649.2200,122.3760  
439292.5380,2132657.0880,121.4220  
439296.2490,2132654.9430,121.4560  
439289.7030,2132646.5050,122.1240  
...
```

I wonder how to do this, what software could I use?